# coldfusion application client side problem

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion

I have the following code:
main.js --> https://controlc.com/5056ed32
With the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PhoneGap SyncDB Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">

<div id="docs"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

In the server side i have a coldfusion application to manage the documents, with a page layout.

Server side is ok, its working.

But client side, when i run, its not working, I have to run syncDB() manually in debug console and I m getting following:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8888/serverbackend/service.cfc?method=getupdates&returnformat=json&date=' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
jquery.min.js:4 GET http://localhost:8888/serverbackend/service.cfc?method=getupdates&returnformat=json&date= net::ERR_FAILED

How can I repair code to get working.
Tell me us please!

If you need entirecode (serverbackend): http://www.raymondcamden.com/enclosures/dbsyncexample.zip

Note: if I browse following adreess in browser (http://localhost:8888/serverbackend/service.cfc?method=getupdates&returnformat=json)

I get json data in plain text withouth problem:

```
[{"deleted":false,"token":"1432493E-D7D7-455B-8C9D0D4F83D11E79","lastupdated":"August, 11 2020 10:19:02 +0200","title":"WSL2","body":"Ubuntu, XFCE y sonido"},{"deleted":false,"token":"891616CB-7D6B-42C3-9075B30CD83E5A78","lastupdated":"August, 11 2020 11:41:55 +0200","title":"Ubuntu","body":"20.04"},{"deleted":false,"token":"F597555D-2F71-40DF-A940FF7AB432F971","lastupdated":"August, 11 2020 16:44:15 +0200","title":"Win","body":"Content"}]
```

Comment: Are you calling the mentioned url from different host? In that case you need to set CORS at web server.

Comment: I set up lucee express with the serverbackend.
I set up mysql database and linked datasource in lucee.
And run from same host.
I have to enable CORS at lucee?

Comment: Can add following code at the end of your getupdate method  and try ? <cfheader name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*">

Comment: I doned with https://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/10/17/Enable-CORS-for-ColdFusion-Services

Comment: The problem is that i have to execute syncDB() manually in debug console. Anything is not working in the script... Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry

So far I have successfully run the coldfusion application. And enable CORS in the app. With what I have achieved with main.js: running syncDB () from Chrome's debug console.

Two questions please:
Why doesn't it load the html layout?
Why aren't the elements clickable, why doesn't the layout load?

edited main.js:

```
function init() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",startup);
    startup();
}

var db;
var updateurl = "http://localhost:8888/serverbackend/service.cfc?method=getupdates&returnformat=json";

function dbError(e) {
    console.log("SQL ERROR");
    console.dir(e);
}

function startup() {
    console.log("Starting up...");
    db = window.openDatabase("main","1","Main DB",1000000);
    db.transaction(initDB,dbError,dbReady);
}

function initDB(tx) {
    //tx.executeSql("drop table docs");
    tx.executeSql("create table if not exists docs(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT, body TEXT, lastupdated DATE, token TEXT)");
}

function dbReady() {
    console.log("DB initialization done.");
    //begin sync process
    if(navigator.network && navigator.network.connection.type != Connection.NONE) syncDB();
    else syncDB();
}

function syncDB() {
    /**
    * Process is: What is my latest doc? if any
    * Ask server for changes since then
    */
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("select max(lastupdated) as lastdate from docs", [], function(tx,res) {
            console.log("Will get items after "+res.rows.item(0).lastdate);
            var date = res.rows.item(0).lastdate?res.rows.item(0).lastdate:'';
            $.get(updateurl, {date:date}, function(resp,code) {
                console.log("back from getting updates with "+resp.length + " items to process.");
                //Ok, loop through. For each one, we see if it exists, and if so, we update/delete it
                //If it doesn't exist, straight insert
                resp.forEach(function(ob) {
                    console.dir(ob);
                    db.transaction(function(ctx) {
                        ctx.executeSql("select id from docs where token = ?", [ob.token], function(tx,checkres) {
                            if(checkres.rows.length) {
                                console.log("possible update/delete");
                                if(!ob.deleted) {
                                    console.log("updating "+ob.title+ " "+ob.lastupdated);
                                    tx.executeSql("update docs set title=?,body=?,lastupdated=? where token=?", [ob.title,ob.body,ob.lastupdated,ob.token]);
                                } else {
                                    console.log("deleting "+ob.title+ " "+ob.lastupdated);
                                    tx.executeSql("delete from docs where token = ?", [ob.token]);
                                }
                            } else {
                                //only insert if not deleted
                                console.log("possible insert");
                                if(!ob.deleted) {
                                    console.log("inserting "+ob.title+ " "+ob.lastupdated);
                                    tx.executeSql("insert into docs(title,body,lastupdated,token) values(?,?,?,?)", [ob.title,ob.body,ob.lastupdated,ob.token]);
                                }
                            }

                        });
                    });
                });
            if(resp.length) localStorage["lastdate"] = resp[resp.length-1].lastupdated;
            displayDocs();    
            },"json");
        });

    }, dbError, function() {
        console.log("I'm done with the transaction");
    });
}

function displayDocs() {
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("select title from docs order by title asc", [], function(tx, results) {
            var s = "<h2>Docs</h2>";
            for(var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++) {
                s += results.rows.item(i).title + "<br/>";
            }
            $("#docs").html(s);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: i get app here: https://dzone.com/articles/adding-database

Comment: uploaded code for easy viewing: https://github.com/iecxiv/syncdb